# Should "View Company Page" links on Careers 2.0 sidebar ads open in new window?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, sidebar

I've started seeing the <kbd>view company page</kbd> links at the bottom of the larger featured Careers 2.0 sidebar ads this week and clicked through a handful of them.  Although the direct links to job openings still open in new windows, the <kbd>view company page</kbd> link opens in the current window, navigating me away from Stack Overflow.

Seems like the job opening links and the company page link should both consistently open in new windows, not navigating away from Stack Exchange QA sites.

[image: Careers Company Profile link]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the report meta.michael. This should be fixed now, I went ahead and `target="_blank"`ed all the other links as well, so those should open in a new tab too.

Comment: Confirmed - thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @meta.michael: No prob.